# Why does my UserMailer in dev mode not output Rails.logger.info?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to debug using Rails.logger.info in my user_mailer.rb

Any idea why the Rails.logger.info is not outputting in the user_mailer but it does everywhere else?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post both working and non-working code segments?

Comment: Nothing breaking. I just want to output  the following in my user_mailer method Rails.logger.info 'DO YOU SEE ME NOW' which isn't happening. Ideas?

Comment: Well, my point is we don't have crystal balls - it would be a lot easier to troubleshoot it if you would post the code for a place where it's behaving the way you expect, and a place where it isn't. Asking a general "Is there anything I should know about logger.info, and why it might not be logging," without a code example, is hardly better than simply google'ing the problem.

Comment: try using puts instead or raising an error. if that's working than you are probably logging to the wrong file/output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#sending-messages), it should work just fine within a Mailer.

> To write in the current log use the logger.(debug|info|warn|error|fatal) method from within a controller, model or mailer

You could always just debug using a `puts` statement instead and check the logs for the output.

```
puts "I am inside the Mailer method"
```